# How to make pushpin draggable over the map in bingmap wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, bing-api

I am working on bingmap wpf. I have created pushpins on click event of mouse. Now I need to make it draggable and track the coordinate as per the pushpin location. Anybody has any idea on how to make the pushpin draggable and in which function we need to write code to update when it is released.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 6):

```
Vector _mouseToMarker;
private bool _dragPin;
public Pushpin SelectedPushpin { get; set; }

void pin_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
  SelectedPushpin = sender as Pushpin;
  _dragPin = true;
  _mouseToMarker = Point.Subtract(
    map.LocationToViewportPoint(SelectedPushpin.Location), 
    e.GetPosition(map));
}

private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    if (_dragPin && SelectedPushpin != null)
    {
      SelectedPushpin.Location = map.ViewportPointToLocation(
        Point.Add(e.GetPosition(map), _mouseToMarker));
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: added a mouse up to stop the drag event and all works perfect good sir, thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

solution by Peter Wone works but needs a small fix. Either ***nullify the SelectedPushpin*** or `make _drag = false` when  `MouseButtonState.Pressed = False`.
Complete solution:

```
Vector _mouseToMarker;
private bool _dragPin;
public Pushpin SelectedPushpin { get; set; }
private void pin_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    SelectedPushpin = sender as Pushpin;
    _dragPin = true;
    _mouseToMarker = System.Windows.Point.Subtract(myMap.LocationToViewportPoint(SelectedPushpin.Location), e.GetPosition(myMap));
    
}
private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (_dragPin && SelectedPushpin != null)
        {
            SelectedPushpin.Location =myMap.ViewportPointToLocation(
              System.Windows.Point.Add(e.GetPosition(myMap), _mouseToMarker));
            e.Handled = true;
            
        }
    }
    else
    { _dragPin = false; }
    
}
```

The solution works like this:

1. You attach an event to `MouseDown` event of all pushpins so when you press on mouse while over the pushpin `selectedpushpin` is assigned this pushpin which is then used in the next step for moving it.
2. use the identified `pushpin` in `MouseMove` event of the map component to move it to next location as long as the `mouseleftbutton` is continuously pressed then use the `dragpin` flag to nullify the `selectedpushpin` when the mouse is pressed away from pushpin does not continously drag the previously selected pushpin.